# Adding a widget to a layout

Tags: qt

Although this kind of question has been asked before, I am still facing a bit problem. My changes of the form.ui file are not being reflected. 
Here are my file codes. My aim is to put the form.ui file widget inside the layout of another ui file in my mainwindow.h. My form.ui has a push and radio button.
It's compiling and running but showing only the mainwindow.ui widget and not the form one.

form.h

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Form;
}

class Form : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Form();

private:
    Ui::Form *ui;
};

#endif // FORM_H
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

form.cpp

```
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Form::~Form()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "form.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Form *k = new Form(this);
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(k);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong since I don't know how your main window class form is setup, but have you tried setting your form as the central widget for the main window? Main windows don't really work with layouts. I.E. in the MainWindow constructor try the following code instead: `ui->setupUi(this); Form *k = new Form(this); setCentralWidget( k );`

Comment: no let me rephrase my question in a better way . Now if i have 2 .ui files with some buttons in each . I want to merge them or set one in the horizontal layout of another . Can this be done , if yes then how and if now do you have any alternatives .

Comment: Your code should work. It depends on how is structured your mainwindow.ui (and also if your form.ui is correctly set up, meaning the top widget has its own layout).